# iOS App - Sent Notifications via On-Site Server (No Internet Connection)

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

I am trying to develop an iOS app that delivers time critical alerts to staff when certain events occur (handled by a server on the clients site, on the client network).  This notification needs to be delivered to the iOS device even when the internet is down (since the alert is time critical it cannot wait for internet to come back up), some client's site do lose internet access often enough for this to be an issue. I don't believe that this is achievable via iOS Push Notification since it requires connection to internet. And the issue with local notification is if the device is asleep for some reason they will not get the alert, unless I have an infinite background operation running. Now battery life on devices is not an issue as they will be rotating multiple devices, so if one dies they can log into another iTouch, and charge the old one. The issue I see is that you cannot have an infinite background task running (to deliver the local notifications) and have it in the app store without some sort of VOIP service also added, and this would be given to our clients so it doesn't really fall under the enterprise license. I have email Apple dev support with this question and have not received any response.  Does anyone have any idea the best way to achieve this time sensitive notification (without internet access) with an iOS device?